How listen HTTPS and HTTP on same port depending on host with GO?
I'm writing a reverse proxy in go. I already have a basic setup working, but I want to be able to listen on a port and have it use TLS or not depending on the host. This is my current code:
var sitesManager *sites.SiteManager = sites.CreateSiteManager()

func handleRequest(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    ctx := req.Context()
    svrAddr := ctx.Value(http.LocalAddrContextKey).(net.Addr)
    host := strings.Split(req.Host, ":")[0]
    port := strings.Split(svrAddr.String(), ":")[1]

    origin := host + ":" + port

    site, exists := sitesManager.GetSite(origin)
    if !exists {
        http.Error(res, "Site not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    site.HandleRequest(res, req)
}

func main() {
    manager := &autocert.Manager{
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache("certsCache"),
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        HostPolicy: sitesManager.HostPolicy(),
    }

    registerSite("example.com:80", &sites.RedirectSite{
        Destination: "https://example.com",
        HTTPS:       true,
    },
        manager)
    registerSite("example.com:443", &sites.ReverseProxySite{
        Destination: "http://localhost:8000",
        HTTPS:       true,
    }, manager)

    handler := http.HandlerFunc(handleRequest)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", manager.HTTPHandler(handler))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("HTTPS server failed: %v", err)
    }
}

func registerSite(origin string, site sites.Site, certManager *autocert.Manager) {
    portString := strings.Split(origin, ":")[1]
    port, _ := strconv.Atoi(portString)
    portExists := sitesManager.IsPortRegistered(port)

    defer sitesManager.RegisterSite(origin, site)

    if portExists {
        return
    }
    if site.ShouldUseTLS() {
        go func() {
            tlsServer := &http.Server{
                Addr:      ":" + portString,
                Handler:   http.HandlerFunc(handleRequest),
                TLSConfig: certManager.TLSConfig(),
            }
            err := tlsServer.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("HTTPS server failed: %v", err)
            }
        }()
    } else {
        go func() {
            err := http.ListenAndServe(":" + portString, http.HandlerFunc(handleRequest))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("HTTP server failed: %v", err)
            }
        }()
    }
}

The site manager is just contains a RWMutex and a few maps to handle routing and ensure that servers are started correctly.
Right now something like this would not work correctly:
registerSite("example1.com:8000", &sites.ReverseProxySite{
    Destination: "localhost:3000",
    HTTPS:       false,
}, manager)
registerSite("example2.com:8000", &sites.ReverseProxySite{
    Destination: "localhost:3001",
    HTTPS:       true,
}, manager)

Is it possible to listen on same port for both http and https?

"Is it possible to listen on same port for both http and https?" - in theory it is possible to determine based on peeking into the first few bytes from the client if this is plain HTTP or TLS (i.e. HTTPS). But in practice almost no software supports HTTP and HTTPS on same port and what you want to do is a unusual requirement with no easy support in existing software. Is there any other reason beside "but I want to" for requiring the same port for both in your reverse proxy? Clients don't expect this to be the same port anyway.

Yes, I am prototyping a remote access service focused on the brazilian Home assistant community. Most people are currently using cloudflare tunnels which forces you to use different subdomains for accessing multiple services. It works and and there are also other things that i'm already improving for the target user but it would be good to be able to offer this flexibility of being able to choose any port.

Check for TLS client hello to distinguish between HTTP and HTTPS.  It's possible to plumb this check in below two instances of http.Server, but I cannot think of an easy way to do it.

I might just force everything to be https, it's probably what most users would want anyway, but it would be a nice to have feature.

@PortalGamesMais: "... but it would be good to be able to offer this flexibility of being able to choose any port ..." - not sure if it would be worth it. It would be a special case for HTTP vs. HTTPS anyway, i.e. it will not enable you to run arbitrary application protocols on the same port. Other application protocols like FTP, SMTP, IMAP, POP ... expect the server to send the first application data and in this case one cannot distinguish the application protocol based on the clients data - one would need to have different ports.
